# Alternating quotients of (2,3,7;10)

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

It was shown that the only quotient of the group $G := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{10} \rangle$ of the form PSL(2, q) is PSL(2, 41). That lead me to consider other families of simple groups. The alternating groups seem the easiest family to consider.

Are there any alternating quotients of G? I have calculated (using GAP) that there are none up to degree 126, and I am trying to go up to 168.